# Libreoffice-calc: Apply a macro to a csv-file on the command-line

Tags: libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

With Libreoffice/Openoffice it is rather straightforward to do these steps:

- Import csv file
- Copy macro from another file
- Run macro
- Remove macro
- Save file in csv and xls formats (no macros, just data)

Is it possible to do that on the command line?

Comment: Cannot you create an empty file with that macro, adding the export as csv file in the last line of the macro and recall it from command line? Maybe you can find interesting some example on how to access macro by commandline [here](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=8232)

Comment: @Hastur: I still need the data as input for the macro.

Comment: Can't you save the macro in the "My Macros" container instead of inside the file?  That way you could skip the "copy macro" and "remove macro" steps.

Comment: @Lyrl: True - any pure command-line solution will be fine